# How to enter different whitespaces in Pages?

Tags: keyboard, pages

How can I use whitespace of different size in Pages? I only know simple space by hitting the `space` bar and the fixed space (no word wrap) using `alt-space`.

Is it possible to get a n-, t- or numeric space (unicode `2000` to `200A`) using the keyboard? The only possibility I found so far is to use the *character viewer*, search for "*space*" and click through the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unicode Hex Input

You can use Unicode Hex Input to enter the characters that you want. Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Input Sources and enable Unicode Hex Input. Then you can enter the characters by holding ⌥ and typing the Unicode code.

### Multi-stroke Key Bindings

You can edit ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict and create a multi-stroke key binding for each of the characters that you want to enter. More information is available on this blog post:

- http://blog.macromates.com/2006/multi-stroke-key-bindings/

### Press and Hold

1. Navigate to `System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/Resources/`.
2. Backup the `Keyboard-en.plist` file.
3. Append the following to the `Keyboard-en.plist` file (before the closing `</dict></plist>`).

   ```
   <key>Roman-Accent-t</key>
   <dict>
       <key>Direction</key>
       <string>right</string>
       <key>Keycaps</key>
       <string>t                   ​     　 </string>
       <key>Strings</key>
       <string>t                   ​     　 </string>
   </dict>
   ```

   <sup>There are a number of different spaces included in the strings above.</sup>

Feel free to change the `Roman-Accent-t` to any character you wish, providing it does not already have Press & Hold keys assigned.

### Text Shortcuts

Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Text and enter some shortcuts.

[image: Text Shortcuts]

Comment: I added a multi stroke key binding using a DefaultKeyBinding.dict file with ^~space as a dead key, thanks